# Why would I get "SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xa3'" when running celeryd?

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, virtualenv, celery

I am trying to run celeryd with Django & Virtualenv on Ubuntu and I am getting this error:

```
celeryd-multi v2.4.5
> Starting nodes...
    > celery.heron:   File "/sites/.virtualenvs/myproject/bin/python", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xa3' in file /sites/.virtualenvs/myproject/bin/python on line 2, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
* Child terminated with failure code 1
FAILED
```

I thought it was an encoding issue, but not sure where. I added `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` to my celeryd-multi script, as well as to my manage.py script, and the actual .py file that has the task code, but that didn't solve it.

This is my `/etc/default/celeryd` config file:

```
CELERYD="/sites/.virtualenvs/myproject/bin/python /sites/dev.myproject.co/code/myproject/manage.py celeryd"

CELERYD_CHDIR="/sites/dev.myproject.co/code/myproject"

DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="settings"

CELERYD_OPTS="-v 2 -B -s celery -E"

CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/sites/dev.myproject.co/logs/celery.log"

CELERYD_USER="www-data"

CELERYD_GROUP="www-data"
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you trying to execute the Python interpreter binary as a Python script?

Comment: Yes that looks like what's happening. See the answer & comments below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @gravitron and @Wooble's hints, I solved this by adding the following to my celeryd config:

```
# Python interpreter from environment.
ENV_PYTHON="/sites/.virtualenvs/myproject/bin/python"

# How to call "manage.py celeryd_multi"
CELERYD_MULTI="$ENV_PYTHON $CELERYD_CHDIR/manage.py celeryd_multi"

# How to call "manage.py celeryctl"
CELERYCTL="$ENV_PYTHON $CELERYD_CHDIR/manage.py celeryctl"
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not an encoding issue. Take a look at what file has the encoding issue:

> /sites/.virtualenvs/myproject/bin/python

It looks like celery is trying to parse your CELERYD variable as a python file, despite it actually being the python binary. Try removing the python binary string from the start of the CELERYD variable declaration.

Comment: In that case how would I make sure that it runs the correct version of python that's in my virtualenv? E.g., when I remove that line it tries to run the manage.py celerdy without the virtualenv activated, and so I get errors that it can't import modules (like djcelery for instance).